# Oil in my radiator fluid tank?

Tags: ford, cooling-system, head-gasket

I have a 97 Ford F350 with the 7.3l powerstroke diesel engine.

There's oil where my radiator fluid should be.

Do I have a blown head gasket?

Comment: Very likely... :(

Answer (score 2):

With a diesel like this, it may also be a bad EGR cooler - fairly common, and a bit less work than a head. A pressure test or closer inspection should be able to confirm.

Comment: This is the most common cause

Comment: My niece had the same thing and the cooler failed , I guess this is common I know an old question but this answer I thought should get an upvote

Answer (score 1):

Highly likely it is either a blown head gasket or a cracked engine block. Check for milky gummy (lubricating) oil in engine (check under the oil cap and the dip stick). Even if the oil is fine, the fact that oil has found it's way into your radiator means pulling the head off for further inspection/repair.

Answer (score 0):

Very possible. Some ways to check:

1. Check you oil, and see if it looks like coolant contaminated it. (Milky)
2. Check engine for compression, as the gasket would allow gas to escape.
3. Check you cooling system for leaks, as it would go into you cylinders.